# How to create modal and non-modal dialogs in Dart Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Does anyone know how I can create custom modal and nonmodal dialogs with dart polymer?

Answer (score 0):

Using this pub package: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bootjack

you can use the Bootstrap modal components in your polymer templates.

However The bootstrap CSS selectors don't work out of the box with elements inside an custom element (no matter what value for applyAuthorStyles is set) so I've just been putting the modal element inside a conditional template like so:

```html
<template if="{{ visible }}">
```

to control it's visibility, e.g

```html
<template if="{{ visible }}">
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
```

and so on. If you just want to create "custom modal" components, it's just to use templates and CSS as bootstrap does.

Comment: The bootstrap CSS selectors don't work out of the box with elements inside an custom element (no matter what value for applyAuthorStyles is set).

Comment: ah, thanks. good to know, I've updated the answer with that info, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Moore has ported his widgets.dart to Polymer recently (Dart port of Bootstrap widgets).
I tried them a while ago when they were web_ui elements and I found them quite good.

It seems that the polymer version is not yet published to pub.dartlang.org

With a git dependency the most current version from his Github repository can be used:

```yaml
dependencies: 
  widget:
    git: git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git
```

[Modal.html](https://github.com/dart-lang/widget.dart/blob/master/lib/components/modal.html)

Comment: widgets.dart v0.27 seems to still use Web UI. How do you get the ported version?

Comment: extendes my answer how to get the most current version directly from Github.